# Proof clarification measure given by integral

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions, simple-functions

While studying measure theory, I encountered a simple proposition which contains a step I was not able to follow. First, here are some relevant definitions(not all of them, since there would be too many):

**Definition:** A real-valued function is simple if it has only a finite number of values.

A simple measurable function can be represented in the form
$$
\varphi=\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j} \chi_{{E}_{j}}
$$

where $a_{j} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\chi_{{E}_{j}}$ is the characteristic function of a set $E_{j}$ in X.

**Definition:** We define the integral of $\varphi$ with respect to $\mu$ to be the extended real number
$$
\int \varphi d \mu=\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j} \mu\left(E_{j}\right)
$$

**What the book states and proves:** If $\lambda$ is defined for $E$ in $\boldsymbol{X}$ by
$$
\lambda(E)=\int \varphi \chi_{E} d \mu
$$
then $\lambda$ is a measure on $X$.

**Proof:**

Observe that
$$
\varphi \chi_{E}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j} \chi_{E_{j} \cap E}
$$

and that
$$
\lambda(E)=\int \varphi \chi_{E} d \mu=\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j} \int \chi_{E_{j} \cap E} d \mu
$$

**The above expression is the issue for me.** Why does
$$\int \varphi \chi_{E} d \mu=\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j} \int \chi_{E_{j} \cap E} d \mu$$ holds?

The author is taking the summand $\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j}$ out of integral, *but I dont know why this is valid*, since $a_{j} \in \mathbb{R}$ and therefore the sum may be negative, which is a problem since we only know so far that
$$
\int c \varphi d \mu=c \int \varphi d \mu
$$
where $c \geq 0$.

**References:** The elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure by Robert G. Bartle

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: I went through the Bartle. OP should specify that the above integral is only for *non-negative* simple functions.

---

He didn't manipulate any integral. We have that $\mathbb{I}_E\varphi$ is a simple function:
$$\mathbb{I}_E\varphi=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\mathbb{I}_{E_k\cap E}$$
So its integral (in OP) is defined as
$$\int \mathbb{I}_E\varphi \,d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^na_k\mu(E_k\cap E)$$
We also know that $\mathbb{I}_{E_k\cap E}$ is a (very) simple function, so
$$\int \mathbb{I}_{E_k\cap E}d\mu = \mu(E_k\cap E)$$
Therefore
$$\int \mathbb{I}_E\varphi \,d\mu=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\int \mathbb{I}_{E_k\cap E}d\mu $$

Comment: Nice!!! Just to be sure, one can say that $\mathbb{I}_{E} \varphi$ is simple since it is a product of two simple functions $\varphi$ and $\mathbb{I}_{E}$, correct?

Comment: @Lucas the product of simple functions is a simple function

Comment: Yes, and that is why the product between $\varphi$ and $\mathbb{I}_{E}$ is still simple, correct?

Comment: @Lucas yes. Always check measurability though

Comment: mesurability regarding the set $E$?

Comment: Let the measurable space be $(X,\mathcal{A})$. If you have $f,g $ measurable simple functions then $f\cdot g$ is a measurable simple function. So both $f$ and $g$ have to be measurable for that to hold. $I_E$ is measurable if $\sigma(I_E) \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. This means that $\{\emptyset,E,E^c,X\}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$.